# Как реализовать загрузку фуйлов по url на php?

Tags: php

Есть sql, таблица в которой прописаны url, для картинок. Как на php можно реализовать скрипт, который будет постоянно качать картинки из таблицы, если в таблице будут появляться ссылки на сами изображения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В реализации скачивания Вам поможет одно из решений: [Curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php), [fopen](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
file_put_contents("myfile.zip", fopen("http://example.com/file.zip", 'r'));
```

Для реализации проверки таблицы скачивания необходимо написать демона или скрипт запускающийся по крону каждые n-времени, который будет проверять таблицу и запоминать последний id, который был обработан. Возможно, самым простым решением это будет добавить поле в таблицу state, которое будет отображать состояние файла (NEW, WORK, DONE, FAILED) и выбирать на скачивание все файлы, которые NEW.

Подобные задачи обычно в многопоточных решениях решаются через очередь задач (напр. RabbitMq), скрипт пишущий в базу, подцепляется в очередь и кидает туда задания, которые получают воркеры (consumers).